# How do i list all the controllers/services of a grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

How do I list all the controllers/services of a grails plugin.
Or 
How do I know the pluin name of a given GrailsApplication class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Artifacts from plugins are annotated with the `GrailsPlugin` annotation to add metadata about their source. So you can use that to find whether the controller/service/etc. is from the application or a plugin like this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.metadata.GrailsPlugin

for (type in ['controller', 'service']) {

   for (artifactClass in ctx.grailsApplication."${type}Classes") {

      def clazz = artifactClass.clazz

      def annotation = clazz.getAnnotation(GrailsPlugin)
      if (annotation) {
         println "$type $clazz.name from plugin '${annotation.name()}'"
      }
      else {
         println "$type $clazz.name from application"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a newly created Grails application, the grails-app/views/index.gsp has the following:

```
<g:each var="c" in="${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.sort { it.fullName } }">
    <li class="controller"><g:link controller="${c.logicalPropertyName}">${c.fullName}</g:link></li>
</g:each>
```

You can get services in a similar fashion.

Comment: Basically my application is divided into several plugins. I want add another plugin which will list the plugins and controllers/Services within each plugin.